# Rule enforcing consistency of a logical set

Tags: logic, axioms

The *principle of explosion states* that a single contradictory statement among a logical set is enough to prove all propositions wrong. So, for a set to be considered valid, it must be consistent*.

What is the name of the rule, axiom or principle that demands such consistency for a logical set of propositions to be valid (and so avoid falling into the previous)? Aristotle's law of *non contradiction* solves the issue for a single statement, but not for a set.

I know I'm possibly looking for glasses I'm already wearing, but I just can't find it... Thanks in advance.

* UPDATED (thanks, @MauroAllegranza): (was)"a set must be logically consistent": I didn't mean that all sets MUST be consistent. I seek for the axiom/rule/condition that determines the consistency of a set.

Comment: "The principle of explosion states that a single contradictory statement among a logical set is enough to prove **all** propositions. "

Comment: "So, a set must be logically consistent." NO; there are inconsistent sets of propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of sentences is called *inconsistent* if one can derive a contradiction from it and *[consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency)* otherwise. There's no law requiring every set to be consistent.